# deadlock on not buffered channel

Tags: go, channel

I'm currently following the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/list) tutorial and got to the section on channels, as I was doing some testing I found an weird behavior I'm struggling to understand

the following code produces a deadlock error

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    c <- "test"
    fmt.Printf("%v", <- c)
}
```

but doing one of the following things fixes the code

using a buffered channel:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 1)
    c <- "test"
    fmt.Printf("%v", <- c)
}
```

or setting the value to the channel on a different thread

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func(){c <- "test"}()
    fmt.Printf("%v", <- c)
}
```

what is the underlying reason for the first version of the code to produce a deadlock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the channel has no buffer, `c <- "test"` will block until something reads from c. Since the reader comes after the write it will never reach the read and deadlock.

If the channel has a buffer, `c <- "test"` writes to the buffer and does not have to wait for a reader. The reader then reads from the channel buffer.

This is all because the reader and writer are in the same goroutine and so must execute one statement after the other. If the reader and writer were in different goroutines, the writer goroutine can block until the reader goroutine reads. Because of this, buffers are often unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

Writing to an unbuffered channel will only succeed if there is another goroutine that reads from that channel. In the first case, you have only one goroutine, the main goroutine, that writes to an unbuffered channel, and there is no other goroutine that can read from it, so it is a deadlock.

The second one works, because the channel is buffered, and writing succeeds by filling the buffer. A second write without a read will deadlock.

The third one works, because write happens in a separate goroutine, which waits until the read in the first goroutine runs.

Comment: "The second one works, because the channel is buffered, and writing succeeds by filling the buffer. A second write without a read will deadlock." It didn't, worked just fine

Comment: Second write, before the read, will block indefinitely.

Comment: Due to the size of the  buffer in my example but not because of the value never being read [test](https://play.golang.org/p/jJQxvDKCYgg).

Comment: The size of the buffer in your question is 1, but in your test it is 2. Change that to 1, and it will deadlock.

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were saying the second one will fail after the second write because the value was not consume and not due to the size of the buffer